# Getter and setter in ViewModel for primitive properties in an INotifyPropertyChanged Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, getter-setter

I'm currently working on a project which leverages the MVVM pattern, and have came across this scenario.

Supposed a class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged contains some properties, for example

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string rabbit;
    public string Rabbit
    {
        get { return rabbit; }
        setter { rabbit = value; OnPropertyChanged("Rabbit"); }
    }
}
```

Now, I wish to write a ViewModel which wraps around Model, exposing the properties of Model together with additional properties (commands, etc).

The problem comes when writing the getters and setters for the properties already existing in Model. I have commented out the specific portion of the code.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Model modelObject;
    public string Rabbit
    {
        get { return modelObject.rabbit; }
        setter 
        { 
            modelObject.rabbit = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Rabbit"); // Should OnPropertyChanged be called here?
        }
    }

    public ViewModel(Model modelObject)
    {
         this.modelObject = modelObject;
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I should call OnPropertyChanged again in the ViewModel. Since the View binds to the ViewModel but should not be able to access the model, it seems only logical to do so.

(P.S. the reason I made my model observable is the same model will be used elsewhere apart from the GUI in the same memory space, where there is also a need to be notified of changes to the model.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the basic issues with MVVM, with a few different philosophies about how to solve it.

Your current approach is fine, and very pure MVVM. The drawback is the amount of work required.

> I am not sure if I should call OnPropertyChanged again in the ViewModel.

You will have to, the INPC of the Model does not help the databinding. You will also have to subscribe your ViewModel to the Model.PropertyChanged and echo these changes in the VM.

Another, acceptable, approach is to expose the Model as a public property (with INPC) and bind with `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Rabbit}" />`

You can have a look at the picture [here](https://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/archive/mvvm/wpf-line-of-business-introduction/). Notice the large block of arrows in the top-right corner, these represent the various solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are two scenarios for this issue:

**1. View-Model that wraps around a model object, which looks like your scenario.**

and for that there are two sub options:

1a) the model object already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` per the properties you want use in the view.
In that case your can derive the model.

```
public class ViewModel : Model 
{
   public ViewModel(){} //parameterless c-tor used for mock for the view.
   public ViewModel(Model model)
   {
      //Copy all model properties to view-model properties.
      //Assuming you get from "outside" a model or Data transfer object.
   } 
}
```

1b) the model object does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`or not for all the properties you want to use in the view. in that case you need to contain the model.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   protected Model model {get;} //C# 5 assumed..

   public ViewModel() //parameterless c-tor used for mock for the view.
   {
       model = new Model();
   } 

   public ViewModel(Model model)
   {
      this.model = model;
   }

   public string SomeProperty
   {
     get { return Model.SomeProperty; } 
     set
     { 
       Model.SomeProperty = value; 
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventsArgs(this, "SomeProperty"));
     }
   }
}
```

If we analyze carefully those examples, we can see that the pattern used in the first one has a very serious constrain, it was not written to serve the view.. instead it is written to parallel the Model properties... which means that if I want to add another Model in the system to that view-model I will have to diverse from the pattern and will end up with code that actually going to look like what is written in the 2nd example.

**2. View-Model that wraps around a view.**

Well in order to write that one - again I look at the 2nd example from the previous option and all looks correct to this scenario as well.

Conclusion: View-Model wraps around a view - and 99% of the times a specific view. So use option 1b for every View-Model you write and regardless of how your model is coded.

To complete the understanding process of this issue, consider this view-model example and you will acknowledge quickly that there is no "nice" way to write it using the pattern in example 1a:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   protected ModelType1 model1 {get;}
   protected ModelType2 model2 {get;}

   public ViewModel() //parameterless c-tor used for mock for the view.
   {
      model1= new ModelType1();
      model2= new ModelType2();
   }

   public ViewModel(ModelType1 model1, ModelType2 model2)
   {
      this.model1 = model1;
      this.model2 = model2;
   }

   public string SpecialProperty
   {
     get { return $"{model1.SomeProperty}.{model2.SomeOtherProperty}"; } 
     set
     { 
       var arr = value.Split('.');
       model1.SomeProperty = arr[0];
       model2.SomtOtherProperty = arr[1];
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventsArgs(this, "SpecialProperty"));
     }
   }
}
```

I hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are going to simply wrap the model then you will need to also call `OnPropertyChanged` again. This is because your view binds to the viewmodel, not to the model, in this case your viewmodel is simply offering a layer of redirection.

If you are looking at it and thinking there must be a simpler way, and thinking you could just specify a binding path that goes through the viewmodel property and directly to the property on the model - it sounds simple and easy (and it is), but don't do it. This quickly leads to an anti pattern once your project starts getting bigger, and violates the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (and basically nullifies the purpose of the viewmodel).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, else the `View` bound to the view model will not be notified of any changes.

Note that if the `Model` is shared and updated elsewhere (another `View`, perhaps), this `View` will not be updated as the notification will be raised by the model.  The `ViewModel` would need to listen to changes on the `Model` and then raise the relevant property changes on the `ViewModel`.

A more pragmatic solution is often to expose the `Model` and bind directly to that, though some would view that pragmatism as heresy.  The choice is yours - a quick google will reveal various opinions and some pros/cons.  Even the other answers give some!